# Add outer borders using xlsxwritter

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe and I want to set outer borders. I tried the below code but it adds border to each and every cell within 'A1:I83' range. I only want to add outer thick border:

```
border_format=workbook.add_format({
                            'border':1,
                            'align':'left',
                            'font_size':10
                           })
worksheet_rating_input.conditional_format('A1:I83' , { 'type' : 'no_blanks' , 'format' : border_format})
```

Comment: You could go with eight separate border formats and just go around the outside of your data.  I hope there is a better solution than this.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do it is to set the format of J1 through J183 with a thick left border and set the format of A184 to I184 to have a thick top border.

I've posted a fully reproducible example of this below.  In my example, I make use of [df.shape](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) to set the borders dependant on dimensionality of my dataframe.

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating a dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(182, 9), columns=list('ABCDEFGHI'))
column_list = df.columns
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

leftFormat = workbook.add_format({'left': 5})
topFormat = workbook.add_format({'top': 5})

for row in range(0, df.shape[0] + 1):
    worksheet.write(row, df.shape[1], '', leftFormat)

for col in range(0, df.shape[1]):
    worksheet.write(df.shape[0] + 1, col, '', topFormat)

worksheet.freeze_panes(1, 0) #freezing top row 

writer.save()
```

With Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]